# Reading From Text-file and Implementing Switch Statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I need help to read data from text file and give output based on user input.

Here is data I have saved in notepad under "data.txt" file

```
C|C,370,0.154 
C||C,680,0.13
C|||C,890,0.12
C|H,435,0.11 
C|N,305,0.15
C|O,360,0.14
C|F,450,0.14 
C|Cl,340,0.18 
O|H,500,0.10 
O|O,220,0.15
O|Si,375,0.16 
N|H,430,0.10
N|O,250,0.12 
F|F,160,0.14  
H|H,435,0.074
```

this is how I have data in notepad. yes, each entry is separated by comma

I know basic reading operation `Scanner` class reads line and spits out text from each line but this time I am inputting either number of bonds or bond length and it gives me the output of remaining two value.

Assignment:

[image]

---

**No, I am not here to ask you to do homework but rather help me learn the process.**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

public class LearnReadText
{
    public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String strResponse="";
        do
        {
          System.out.println("\nChapter 7");

          System.out.println("L - Bond Length");
          System.out.println("N - Bond Numbers (1=single, 2=double, 3=triple)\n");
          System.out.println("Q - quit program.");
          strResponse = input.nextLine();
          strResponse = strResponse.toUpperCase();


          Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
          file.close();

        } 


        while (!strResponse.equals("Q"));
        System.out.println("\n\nThank you and have a nice day.");


       input.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I have saved text file in same location as java code.

Comment: Baby, it doesn't work like this here - we're not here to do your work (and if someone will - it definitely won't "help" you because you'll learn nothing out of it). Go and read tutorials of how to use Scanner to read a file (there are many of them with examples). Try to implement it by yourself, and when you run into a concrete problem (like an error that you googled but still - don't know how to handle) - then post it here and we'll help you.

Comment: Well, did you learn any splitting operations on strings? Perhaps `indexOf` and `substring`?

Comment: First read the file into a data structure. Then fire queries against the loaded data. The code you've shared does nothing much as of right now.

Comment: @RealSkeptic No as of right now we are doing basic programming.

Comment: If you do not use any splitting or string manipulation methods, you cannot solve this assignment. I suggest you consult with your tutor about what you are supposed to use.

Comment: @alfasin Tutorials are useful sure but not straight forward. I just said I know how to use Scanner class now just cant not connect dot between Switch Statement and text file.